# Integrating the volume form over $S^n$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

On $S^n$ consider the volume form $\omega = \sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} (-1)^{i - 1} x_i dx_1 \ldots \widehat{dx_i} \ldots dx_{n+1}$ where the hat indicates to omit that term. I wish to compute $\int_{S^n} \omega$ to conclude that it is not exact (by finding that integral to be not $0$ and applying Stokes' theorem). As the definition of integral via partitions of unity is not exactly practical to compute explicitly, I tried using spherical coordinates to parametrize $S^n$:

$\Phi(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n) = (\cos(\phi_1), \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2), \ldots, \sin(\phi_1) \ldots \sin(\phi_{n-1}) \cos(\phi_n), \sin(\phi_1) \ldots \sin(\phi_n))$.

To do this I tried to compute $\Phi^{*} \omega = \sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} (-1)^{i - 1} \Phi_i d\Phi_1 \ldots \widehat{d\Phi_i} \ldots d\Phi_{n + 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n + 1} (-1)^{i - 1} \Phi_i J(\Phi^i) d\phi_1 \ldots d\phi_n$ where $J(\Phi^i)$ is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the function $\Phi^i = (\Phi_1, \ldots, \widehat{\Phi_i}, \ldots, \Phi_n)$.

My problem is that computing this determinant looks quite unwieldy. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to compute this?

Comment: Ted has given arguably the simplest answer, but as a side note, an inductive argument gives a tractable computation. (At some point I've done the computation in stereographic coordinates; it seems likely that spherical coordinates will work equally well. "The details are left as an exercise." :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A far easier approach is to apply Stokes's Theorem (in the other direction), noting $S^n = \partial(D^{n+1})$, and you get $$\int_{S^n}\omega = \int_{D^{n+1}}d\omega = (n+1)\text{vol}(D^{n+1}).$$

Comment: Well that's simpler! Thanks